# How can I obtain the current date in this specific format?

Tags: java, date

how can I obtain the current date in this format: **06-MAG-15** (day-month-year) in Java?

Tnx

Comment: Please.... write code!

Comment: I'm italian so I know... MAG is a short for May (in italian 'Maggio').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Comment: This is the easiest method. 

[Try this article for more detail.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like (I suppose you need the italian locale):

```
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ITALIAN); //dd-MMM-yy
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    return strDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ```
> public class SimpleDateFormat
> extends DateFormat
> ```
>
> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates
>    in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date → text),
>    parsing (text → date), and normalization.

You should define the date format as per your requirement using the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

You may now use this object to format your `Date` as per following usage:

```
Date date = new Date();
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

I will recommend you to go through the documentation to learn more about date formatting in Java. Hope this helps!

Comment: Watch out!  SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
     Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ITALIAN);
        String currentDate = formatedDate.format(date);
        System.out.println("Formated date " + currentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8,

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, 5, 6);
    DateTimeFormatter italianFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ITALIAN);   
    String dateItalianStr = date.format(italianFormatter);
```